# Ninject : Resolving an object by type _and_ registration name/identifier

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am looking for a way to do something like this with Ninject :

```
// Sample from the Unity application block
IMyService result = myContainer.Resolve<IMyService>("Data");
```

( from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440957.aspx )

Is it possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ninject 2.0 has this capability:

```
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceA>().Named("Data");
Bind<IMyService>().To<MyServiceB>().Named("SomethingElse");

kernel.Get<IMyService>("Data"); // will return MyServiceA
```

Comment: does windsor have something same like this ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do that directly in Ninject, but you can use [Contextual Binding](http://www.google.com/search?q=ninject+Contextual+Binding) instead.